# Is there any way to store the datatype of "MSALAccount using swift ui" in core data?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, swiftui, uikit

I´m trying to implement MSAL authentication. In my login function Im getting an user account of type MSALAccount.

I´m trying to store that to core data. Is it possible to do that? Or is there any other way to store the data inside my app.

This is my login function:

```
func login() {

    let config = MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig(clientId: "my client -id-here")
    let application = try? MSALPublicClientApplication(configuration: config)
    let scopes:[String] = []
        let viewController = UIViewcontroller() 
        let webviewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters(authPresentationViewController: self)
        
    let interactiveParameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: scopes, webviewParameters: webviewParameters)
    application!.acquireToken(with: interactiveParameters, completionBlock: { (result, error) in
                    
        guard let authResult = result, error == nil else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        let accessToken = authResult.accessToken
        let account = authResult.account
        let accountIdentifier = authResult.account.identifier
    })
       
}
```

Comment: Did you fixed this? any updates please let me know, I need this

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the documentation, but is not too clear.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-ios

The class MSALPublicClientApplication has a getCurrentAccountWithParameters method that gets the current MSALAccount

Here is the doc:
https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/Classes/MSALPublicClientApplication.html#/c:objc(cs)MSALPublicClientApplication(im)getCurrentAccountWithParameters:completionBlock:

So you can use this method to retrieve the current MSALAccount when you need it without need to store it yourself.

Hope this helps!